# regex negative with negative match for part of string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I've tried several versions, for negative lookahead or negative lookbehind, found here on SO and all over the web, but I just can't get it to work.

I want, from a large set of text, extract html links, except if they are anchored with an image.
Examples:

```
<a href="somelink">sometext</a>  <-- match and grab somelink
<a href="anotherlink"><img src="someimage"></a>  <-- ignore link
```

I've tried

```
preg_match_all('/<a href="(.*?).*?>.*?<\/a>^((?!<img).)*/', $string), $matches);
preg_match_all('/<a href="(.*?).*?>.*?<\/a>(?<!img )/', $string, $matches);
```

and other similar version

Comment: Maybe try this: `<a href="(.*?)">[^(?:<img)]` Unfortunately, this will only work if the `img` tag is right after the `href` tag. You can test it [here](http://regex101.com/r/aF4vA5/1). Although you should probably test on your actual text

Comment: I don't mind if it only works with the img tag right after the href. I used your example and modified it to allow more text in the link tag than the href attribute. What ends up in the result array is the following; it grabs the link before the first image tag, but the following correct link is excluded from the result. So for me it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Let's not use regular expressions for this. Parse the HTML, get all the anchor tags and check whether they contain `<img>` elements.

```
<?php
$html = '<a href="somelink">sometext</a><a href="anotherlink"><img src="someimage"></a>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

$anchors = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach ($anchors as $a) {
    if ($a->getElementsByTagName('img')->length === 0)
        echo $doc->saveHTML($a);
}
```

Yes, it's longer but it's also a hell of a lot more readable and pretty self-documenting.

Output:

```
<a href="somelink">sometext</a>
```

Comment: I'd like to solve this with a regex if possible. It would let me quickly filter out links not formatted in a specific way.

Comment: @Borje It is probably possible to write a regex that is "good enough" for your needs but this does the job and is a lot more flexible. If you use a regex there'll almost always be an edge case that catches you out. Perhaps this method could be adapted to cater to your requirements. I suggest that you edit your question to be more specific.

Comment: I appreciate you taking your time, trying to help me but I can't really be more specific than I am. I need to grab links from a text. I'd like to do so with a regex. From the result I want to exclude links that's displayed with an image. It's the exclusion part I'm having problems with. If I wish to filter the links by checking the structure of the elements or by preceding text, I'll be able to handle that by modifying my regex myself.